# Suppress "Operation not permitted" error from socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a small utility application that handles sockets, both TCP and UDP. Occasionally, I get the error "Operation not permitted" printed to stderr. My issues is, I handle the errors based on the return codes of the socket functions (and occasionally errno), and don't print anything. Thus, this message must be coming from one of the socket calls. I am not sure which one, as this message occurs so infrequently, it has been difficult to debug, but I think it is either coming from `socket` or `sendto`.

Is there a way to suppress all messages from being printed? I can handle the errors myself, I do not need the system doing it uncontrolled on my behalf.

Note, this is a Linux only application.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using any library on top of sockets API? The functions used to work with sockets are not supposed to print anything to stderr. I'd suggest using `strace` and/or `ltrace` to check where this message originates from in first place.

Comment: I am not using any library, I am using the system sockets calls directly. I would have thought the calls would not print anything either, but there is only one printf in my entire app, and that simply prints the port number being used when one isn't provided.

Comment: I'd absolutely start with strace'ing the app. Try strace -o log -f -s 1000 ./your_binary  and grep the log for 'Operation not permitted'. Btw, you're absolutely sure it's you application's stderr where this message originates from?

Comment: Almost positive, there is a small chance it might be going to stdout. Again, it happens very infrequently, it is just an annoyance really. Like I said, I gracefuly handle the error conditions, I just don't log them, they are allowed to occur, they are expected to occur occasionally, I just don't need to see this message (or any other) printed.